# Enviar e-mail via PHP no windows server 2008 R Standard com wampserver 2.0

Tags: php, windows, wamp, swiftmailer

Estou utilizando o wampserver 2.0 no windows server 2008 R2 Standard.
No servidor está instalado o SMTP Virtual Server.
No php.ini tenho a seguinte configuração:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = 000.00.000.000 //IP do servidor SMTP, substituí o IP original só para exemplo
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = noreply@meu-dominio.com //coloquei meu-dominio só para o exemplo
;sendmail_path =
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
mail.add_x_header = On
;mail.log =
```

Estou tentando enviar e-mail de duas formas:

1. Utilizando a função "mail()" do PHP, entretanto a seguinte mensagem é retornada:

> SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay email@dominio.com

1. Utilizando a classe Swiftmailer e autenticando o envio, porém a classe retorna true informando que o e-mail foi enviado mas na caixa de correio não há nada, já tentei com o hotmail, gmail, e outros.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver o problema?

Comment: Já tentou alterar a porta SMTP de 25 para 587?

Comment: a porta do servidor é a 25 segundo a informação do administrador do sistema. Mas existe algum problema em utilizar a porta 25? Não é a padrão? O servidor responde na porta 25, o problema é que não chega nada na caixa de correio.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que há algum tempo foi determinado pelo CG de internet no Brasil que a porta 25 seria aposentada, e que seria agora necessário o uso de uma porta segura (SSL ou TLS), com autenticação do usuário, isso para diminuir o SPAM, por esse motivo, e-mails enviados pela porta 25, normalmente estão sendo bloqueados de imediato em muitos servidores, o próprio MTA deve possuir o recurso de autenticação, basta você dar uma olhada na documentação do mesmo.

Você pode dar uma lida no artigo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol para obter mais algumas informações.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas o envio é autenticado, apesar de usar a porta 25 e mesmo assim pode ser considerado spam?

Comment: Olha, como te disse, alguns servidores estão caracterizando dessa forma agora, no header do e-mail normalmente fica os dados de conexão e se não me engano ali fica também a porta utilizada, se for regra do servidor que vai receber o e-mail que e-mails enviados pela porta 25 devem ser considerados SPAM, sim ele será caracterizado como SPAM.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse texto aqui: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s451/sh/23fc6f4e-e8a6-4296-bab5-c0f19f5d2260/515664389536544a0675d6d81d1a07b5
Espero que agora suas dúvidas tenham sido esclarecidas após ler esse texto.